# Uppercase key value returned as lowercase in HTTP response

Tags: javascript, c#, json, httpresponse

In the backend (.net core) I'm making dictionary:

[image]

key can be 'TEST', testAAAA', 'test', 'TEst'  all possible variations.

However this specific result is returned as (image is from postman): [image]

as you see key here is 'mo' instead of 'MO' . Is it possible to make it case sensitive? so that it wouldn't be made lowercase?

in my startup.cs class I have:

```
                opt =>
                {
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
                  //  opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new UnixDateTimeConverter());
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    opt.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                });
```

Comment: there's not really enough context to figure out why it's lowercase in the screenshot, as far as i can tell

Comment: This requires your serializer settings - which library you're using and which options you're passing to the serializer. Some libraries go lowercase by default, others don't. Many of those that do use the rationale that the most common consumer is JavaScript - the typical naming-standard of which is camelCase as opposed to the PascalCase you see in C#.

Comment: updated @McAden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
```

You're specifically feeding in a resolver and a converter that is telling it to update the casing to `camelCase` - both incoming and outgoing.

You'll need to change your settings to have it not do that, or you'll need to implement a custom resolver that does different things depending on the class.

You can see some examples of custom resolvers [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) in the newtonsoft documentation.